# IE firing submit on button even there is no <form> tag

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, form-submit

I know that if we've a `<form>` and an `<input>` with or without `submit` button, on pressing `Enter` key will submit that enclosing form. But, IE is submitting (specifically, clicking the first button it encounters) even when there is no `<form>` tag present.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="alert('button 1 clicked')">button 1</button>
    <button onclick="alert('button 2 clicked')">button 2</button>
    <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

above markup in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BNRuX5ieJDlYLbwzKODZ?p=info).

When '`Enter`' is pressed with in `input` field, '***button 1 clicked***' alert will be seen.

If I surround `<input>` with a `<form>` tag, it is not submitting.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LuWfXpbMWP9MFa3wPTrN?p=info)

This behavior is observed in IE9 and IE 10 too (haven't tested other versions). Is this a bug in IE or if it is not, how to stop this happening?

***Update***: if I add, `type="button"`, the said behavior is not observed. 
Is the default behavior for a `<button>` tag a `submit`? and, only IE is behaving like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/932657/340290 helped me in identifying adding `type="button"` will not cause this effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I add, `type="button"`, the said behavior is not observed. Is the default behavior for a  tag a submit? and, only IE is behaving like this?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932657/340290) helped me in identifying adding `type="button"` will not cause this effect

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent IE from submitting the form by adding **'return false;'** in the **onclick** event. Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="alert('button 1 clicked'); return false; ">button 1</button>
   <button onclick="alert('button 2 clicked'); return false; ">button 2</button>
   <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Moreover you can also prevent the Submit button from submitting the form by adding **'return false'** to it.

Comment: but still button will be clicked. ideally, that should not happen. Adding `type="button"` is correct way of fixing it. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/932657/340290